# js remove object property using array shift

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array and object in js:

```
var number = [23,234,654,3234];
var detail = {
              23:"John",
              234:"Doe",
              654:50,
              3234:"blue"
            };
```

Then using `var remove = number.shift()`, I can get the first value in the array (in this case, 23) and remove it from the array.

I am trying to remove the corresponding property from the object: In this case, it will be `23:"John"`.

I tried `delete detail.remove;` but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: it should be `delete detail['23'];`

Comment: @pryxen It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: ops sorry I forgot the return value is not a string, just remove the single quotes `delete detail[23];`

Comment: `delete detail[number.shift()]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is followed by an expression that should evaluate to a property reference. Your example `delete detail.remove` is in fact correct.

However, if you want to access a property programmatically (or numbered property, such as 23), use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```
// with variable
delete detail[remove];

// with string or integer
delete detail[23];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use variable in obj.variable, the right way is obj[variable].

So try this instead:

```
 delete detail[remove];
```